# Generate SNMP trap with source as Ipv6 address

Tags: snmp, net-snmp, snmp-trap

I have come across simulators which support IPv6 for the host. But i am looking for a simulator where the SNMP trap generator uses the IPv6 address as the source IP or we can externally specify the IPv6 address in the command to generate snmp trap.
Can some one please tell me if you know any simulator which i can use for this.

thanks in advance
-Prateek

Answer (score 0):

This is trivial in MIMIC Simulator, which our company sells.
Here's a sample trap generated within a minute received by our trap receiver:

`% ./trapper --ipv6
    INFO  12/07.11:48:50 - Waiting for traps on port 162 ...
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 - Received a SNMPv1 TRAP. [5 bytes from 2001::1,161]
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 - HEADER :
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 -   community        = public
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 -   enterprise       = 1.3.6.1.4.1.9.1.46
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 -   agent_addr       = 0.0.0.0
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 -   generic_trap     = coldStart(0)
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 -   specific_trap    = 0
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 -   time_stamp       = 51692
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 - MIB :
    INFO  12/07.11:57:08 -   mib              = SNMPv1-TRAPS`